# Limitations of iOS6 Social Framework - can I get Facebook images?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6, frameworks

In my iOS app I need to access the profile pictures of a user's facebook friends. Is this something that can be done with the iOS6 Social framework? Or would I need to use the Facebook API? The documentation for the Social framework is vague in that is says "common uses for the framework are..." but doesn't seem to give any concrete details on what it can or can't do.

Also does anyone have any tips on the best way to get the profile picture images of facebook friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The social framework, by virtue of `SLRequest`, lets you do basically anything with the graph API. The Facebook docs tell you what parameters and permissions you need and then `SLRequest` creates the authenticated request for you and executes it (`performRequestWithHandler:`).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any good references for how to accomplish my task? Seems like all the search results I get are about sharing and posting. I need to pull in profile pictures.

Comment: It's basically the same, but instead of setting POST you set `SLRequestMethodGET`. The parameter and account setup and the execution are just the same.